# querying database in android

Tags: sql, mysql, android, android-emulator

I am building an android app and I have an SQL database stored on a server. I need to either pull the database into android or query the database and have it return information from the tables. I have searched all over the internet but I haven't found anything that explains how to connect to the server from android. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query database in a server from android directly. You have to write PHP scripts to query database from server. You have to keep the php scripts in a web server. And from android application you have to get the data from the php page.

Comment: Ok, so I have search information that the user enters. Would I send that information to the php script then the script would return the information queried from the database to the android app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a reasonably simple way to 'pull' the database or connect to it using some soft of ODBC connection. And I don't think it would be wise to use it even if possible.

I believe the best way to solve your problem would be to implement some sort of REST API interface to your database and fetch data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

actually, despite gypsicoder's answer and several "how to"s on the internet, there is a way to connect/query an SQL database from android

you just have to download the corresponding JDCB. for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/

then you just use the java.sql interfaces/classes to do stuff (mysql has a reference manual at above link)

Comment: turns out though that it is hard to get this to work. you're better off doing the php route :P